# Progressive Web App PWA formats video

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to set up Progressive Web app on a my site. Stop caching effect. It's fine. 
    I'm having trouble deleting the .mp4 videos from the cache once with the active service worker it waits for the entire download request to finish to give the user feedback.

What is the correct approach to take for video files (.mp4, .ogg ....)?

```
var urlsToCache = [
    '/fotos/',
    '/js/jquery.cp.js',
    '/js/sprite.js',
    '/js/dominio.js',
    '/css/sprite.css',
    '/tema/FP/images/', 
    '/tema/FP/style.css?ffff',
    '/tema/FP/favicon.ico'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event){
   event.waitUntil(
       caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache){
            console.log('Opened cache');
            return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
       })
   );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
   event.respondWith(
       caches.match(event.request).then(function(response){
           console.log(event.request);
          // This event waiting finish dowload, this solution is not better 
          //for user in case file video 
          return response || fetch(event.request);
       })
   );
});
```

thank's for any help.

Comment: are you trying to delete video files during the activate event? Or are you trying to alert users when videos have finished downloading?

Comment: Hello David, maybe my English has made it difficult to understand.

I'm trying to cache only static files (js, css, jpg, jpeg). However my service worker routine stop the execution of the video until all the download is finished.I would like the video to be played while downloading the partial content. thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is likely to chunk the video requests. Check out the [Service Worker Sample: Cache Video Sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/prefetch-video/index.html) from Google.

You can see in the `fetch` event they are checking for range requests and handling those as individual requests. You could request short ranges of a couple of seconds from the the video and users would only have to wait for that range to complete before starting to play.

```
  if (event.request.headers.get('range')) {
    var pos =
    Number(/^bytes\=(\d+)\-$/g.exec(event.request.headers.get('range'))[1]);
    console.log('Range request for', event.request.url,
      ', starting position:', pos);
    event.respondWith(
      caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.prefetch)
      .then(function(cache) {
        return cache.match(event.request.url);
      }).then(function(res) {
        if (!res) {
          return fetch(event.request)
          .then(res => {
            return res.arrayBuffer();
          });
        }
        return res.arrayBuffer();
      }).then(function(ab) {
        return new Response(
          ab.slice(pos),
          {
            status: 206,
            statusText: 'Partial Content',
            headers: [
              // ['Content-Type', 'video/webm'],
              ['Content-Range', 'bytes ' + pos + '-' +
                (ab.byteLength - 1) + '/' + ab.byteLength]]
          });
      }));
  } else {
    ...
  }
```